# browser specific css for internet explorer and Firefox only

Tags: css

please help I need wright style for IE only is there any one who know it well also I want Firefox specific css, I am trying to show somthing like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Place something similar to the following in the header.

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
Special instructions for IE 6 here
<![endif]-->
```

This will work for any browser that you choose it to, consider:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
your css in here
<![endif]-->
```

This will display your specified rules if the browser is ie 8 or lower.

Answer (score 1):

**For any mozilla use:**

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() 
{ 
  // Styles for mozilla goes here
}
```

**For a specific IE use the following. Here it is IE 8**

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8specific.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

**For IE 7 and lower versions**

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

**For IE 7 and higher versions**

```
<!--[if gt IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

**OR**

```
<!--[if gte IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

If you want to use **inline CSS for IE**, then instead of linking to a CSS file, add styles in between the condtion.

```
<!--[if gte IE 7]>
        <style>
                  // Style for IE 7 and higher versions.
            </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: The conditional comments like `<!--[if IE]>` are not for *all* IE, but for IE9- only. Since IE10, they aren't supported any more.

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn Thank you for the new knowledge.

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn I have removed that portion from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For IE you can use  :

```
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="iespecific.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

For mozilla, you can use :

```
<style type="text/css">
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    h1 {
        color: red;
    }
    // all styles for mozilla alone
}
</style>
```